# Why Does a Repeated Capture Group Return these Strings?

Tags: python, regex

Can someone explain why following returns 'cc'?

```
>>> re.match('(..)+', 'aabbcc').group(1)
'cc'
```

I was told that because it put each match into group(1), so the last match is 'cc'. Is that true?

Then how to explain following?

```
>>> re.match('(..)+(...)', 'aabbcc').group(1)
'aa'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Repeated Capture Group: The Group Number Stays the Same

The group defined by `(..)` is Group 1. The `+` quantifier repeats it. Every time the engine is able to repeat the group (matching two characters), Group 1 gets overwritten.

- When the engine starts to match, it captures `aa` to Group 1
- It then captures `bb` to Group 1
- It then captures `cc` to Group 1.

When you inspect Group 1, the engine returns `cc`. All other captures are lost.

(The exception is the .NET engine, which also returns `cc` but also allows you to inspect intermediate captures thanks to the CaptureCollection object. It would contain `aa`, `bb` and `cc`.)

**With `(..)+(...)`, Why does Group 1 Contain `aa`? Backtracking!**

To understand this, we again need to follow the path of the regex engine.

- Once again, when the engine starts to match, it captures `aa` to Group 1
- Again, it repeats the `(..)` group and captures `bb` to Group 1
- Again, it repeats the `(..)` group and captures `cc` to Group 1
- The engine now tries to match `(...)`. It fails: there are no characters left to consume.
- The engine **backtracks** both in the string and in the regex pattern. The `+` means one or more times, and we matched `..` three times, so we can give one up, or even two. At this stage, the engine gives up the last match of the quantified `(..)+` group, which is `cc`. We are back to when Group 1 was `bb`.
- The engine tries to match `(...)` again. There are only two characters left: `cc`, so it fails again.
- The engine **backtracks** by giving up the last match of the quantified `(..)+` group, which is `bb`. At this stage, Group 1 is `aa` again.
- The engine tries to match `(...)` again. It succeeds: Group 2 is `bbc`, and Group 1 is `aa`

**Reference**

- [Capture Group Numbering & Naming: The Gory Details](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html)
- [Backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html)

Comment: FYI I added a detailed explanation of the engine internals for the `(..)+(...)` case. Also highly recommend you read the "Gory Details" article linked. :)

Comment: Decided to delete mine, didn't feel like writing a story.

Comment: @hwnd Yes, it's quite interesting to understand how this works, but as you say you have to write the whole engine story. :)

Comment: Hey Deqing, I added lots of details, so please let me know if anything is unclear. :)