# Regex to split a list of integers separated by spaces into groups

Tags: regex

I have a simple list of integers, for example: `1 23 765 23 25 67 12` (numbers don't matter, any length possible). I would like to split this output into one match, with each number in separate group, so I created a regex:

`(\d+)(?:\s(\d+))*`

My understanding of this is as follows:

- capture a number into first group
- find a set of a space (I'm aware `\s` is not only a space) and a number and put this number into next group

But the output I get on Regex101 is different - it only returns first and last of the numbers from my initial list (in this case: `1` and `12`). Here's a [LINK](https://regex101.com/r/PZlHze/1).

Should there be more lines in the output, each line is a separate match, with all integers in it separated into groups.

### Disclaimer

I know I can do this simply by splitting using any programming language that supports string manipulation, but I'm just curious as of why this isn't working and I'm looking for an explanation. I couldn't also find any examples of such a solution over the Internet because after all, every solution I found implied using split() (or however this method is named in `<insert your programming language here>`).

Comment: So, you are only looking for the explanation, and not a solution? Regex101 only supports a limited number of regex flavors. In .NET, Python PyPi regex module, you would get all the captures with that regex.

Comment: I'm not sure that your regex fiddle is actually showing only one match.  To the contrary, I see every number in blue appearing to match the pattern `\d+`.  You might want to ask this in the context of a language or tool other than Regex101.

Comment: There is a nice explanation of an analogous pattern at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857005/why-does-a-repeated-capture-group-return-these-strings. Unless you specify your issue, the question is a dupe of that one.

Comment: The question you linked @WiktorStribiżew seems to answer my question. Looks like I was too focused on the splitting part to search for overwritten groups.

Comment: If you want your question reopened feel free to modify the question to describe a real life issue.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Also, to answer your first question - I thought this example doesn't depend so much on different regex engines, and therefore shouldn't be connected to any language at all.

Comment: @Asunez: No, as I mentioned, there are engines that support a capture stack. One can even configure Boost with C++ to support this feature.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Okay, I can understand this. However, if I would insist on doing this with the default regex engine in Regex101 (which is PCRE), and this only, is it possible at all to generate the output I want? This would be asking for a solution now, so should I edit my question for this?

Comment: :) I don't know, but I'd reopen the question. You might use `\G` based regex with PCRE to match *multiple* substrings. Like [`\G\s*\K\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/7sf8Ig/1)

Comment: However, the above regex will also match numbers in `1 23 765 23 25 67 12 something`. If you only want to match multiple numbers in a string that only consists of whitespace and dogits use [`(?:\A(?=[\d\s]+\z)|\G(?!\A))\s*\K\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/7sf8Ig/2).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `\b` as a word boundary and match each integer in a capturing group like so

```
\b(\d+)\b
```

Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/PZlHze/3
Edit: I want to mention that the regex also requires the `g` global flag to match more than just the first one!

Comment: the `\b`s are not even needed. see https://regex101.com/r/QOt4S5/1

Comment: but this does not answer the 2nd part

Comment: Just like @Fallenhero said - this doesn't answer part 2.